# How to change the direction of evaporation and thus location of condensation?

Tags: physical-chemistry

For a specific region of air, enclosed by a metal box in which a constituent is obviously gaseous $\ce{H2O}$, is there any way in which we can control the location of condensation?

Assume the box is heated, typically we will have condensed $\ce{H2O}$ formed at the ceiling, does anyone have any strategies of condensing water on the inner sides of the box, or maybe at the base?

I feel like I have a limited scope, with the outer-most idea being to stick anhydrous calcium chloride (dessicant) on the inner sides and have a ledge for the water to sit on.

Comment: Heat the ceiling, and water will condense at the base. It is as simple as that.

Comment: Forgot to mention.. Without the use of a heat/electrical source...

Comment: Make the side of the walls a lot cooler than the ceiling? Maybe strap some ice packs onto the walls

Comment: Why would you want to do this by the way?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that water evaporate where the concentration in the air is lower than the vapor pressure some liquid water at a given temperature. Then it will condense at a location where the temperature is lower that the saturation temperature of water at that partial pressure.

Industrially, though, one widely used technique to avoid condensation when the surface temperature is low enough for it to happen is to use hydrophobic coatings to prevent the water vapor from nucleating on certain surfaces. A [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=anti%20condensation%20coating&oq=anti%20condensation%20coating&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.8195j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will reveal lots of these for different applications.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way in which we can control the location of condensation?

Condensation requires a nucleus to start. Droplets will form more readily on surface than in the gas phase, unless it contains impurities such as smoke.

In physics, cloud chambers were used to detect and trace the path of particles. The picture below, from Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_chamber) on cloud chambers, shows the path of a positron:

[image]

The same idea is used at a bigger scale to make it rain by seeding the clouds, see for example [this report](https://www.businessinsider.com/china-sets-aside-millions-to-control-the-rain-2016-7).

> does anyone have any strategies of condensing water on the inner sides of the box, or maybe at the base?

If you use different materials for the different sides of the box, they probably would be more or less efficient in acting as nuclei for condensation. That would be a way to control where condensation occurs even when the temperature is constant throughout.